# Fragment with map: cast issue

Tags: java, android, google-maps

At first try, I followed this post to create the fragment with a map:

https://demonuts.com/android-google-map-in-fragment/

I've followed another posts os the same problem regarding the cast issue:

[Android Studio "error: incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to SupportMapFragment"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52742836/android-studio-error-incompatible-types-fragment-cannot-be-converted-to-suppo)

But I can not figure out how to solve this issue. I have a fragment where I try to include a map and set annotations:

MapFragment.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.kaopiz.kprogresshud.KProgressHUD;
import com.sagaciresearch.sagalocations.LocationMessage;
import com.sagaciresearch.sagalocations.Outlet;
import com.sagaciresearch.sagalocations.R;

import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link MapFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link MapFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private GoogleMap map;
    private Location curLocation;
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }


    public MapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onOutletsMessage(OutletsMessage event) {
        setUpMap(event.outlets);
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onLocationMessage(LocationMessage event) {
        curLocation = event.location;
    }

    void setUpMap(List<Outlet> outlets){
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);;
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

                map.clear(); //clear old markers

                CameraPosition googlePlex = CameraPosition.builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(curLocation.getLatitude(),curLocation.getLongitude()))
                        .zoom(10)
                        .bearing(0)
                        .tilt(45)
                        .build();

                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(googlePlex), 10000, null);

                for(Outlet outlet: outlets)
                {
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(outlet.getLatitude(),outlet.getLongitude()))
                            .title(outlet.getName()));
                }
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment MapFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static MapFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

}
```

fragment_map.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".OutletFragment" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<permission
        android:name="your.package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Still the cast issue at line:

```
mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

Compilation error:

**Fragment cannot be converted to SupportMapFragment error**

Thanks.

Comment: Please add full stacktrace with error

Answer (score 0):

Migrating to androidx fixes this issue as the latest version of the Maps SDK for Android was updated to androidx.

If you're using Android Studio, you can [refactor](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate_an_existing_project_using_android_studio) your app to migrate to androidx very easily.

Hope this helps!